# How to build a DIY Teams Panels device and integrate into existing DIY Teams Rooms Setup

Tags: microsoft-teams

I found some articles explaining quite nicely how to build and set up your own Teams Rooms device based on a simple computer with some peripherals.

I'd now like to take it one step further, and also build my own "Teams Panels" device.
"Teams Panels" is what Microsoft calls touch display devices, that are supposed to be hanging outside of the meeting room, showing info about the status of the room. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/devices/teams-panels

By "Teams Panels" I do NOT mean the touch display device INSIDE the Meeting room, providing control elements for the current meeting. Those are part of the Teams Rooms DIY-setup itself.

While Microsoft does offer certified devices for Teams Panels, I can absolutely not see myself spending a 4-figure-amount for a 7 inch touch display, that does nothing but display the rooms status - for 10+ rooms. 200 bucks is the absolute max for this.

Has anyone ever attempted to set up a Teams Panels device, and could provide some guidance how to set this up?

Or, to be some more precise on the questions in my head:

- In the Microsoft Doc they say, that Teams Panels devices log in with the same account as the Teams Rooms Resource account running on the Teams Rooms device. If it uses the same account, does it actually need to be a seperate physical device registered in Teams - or could it maybe be just another display attached to the actual Teams Rooms device, which is used to run the whole Teams Rooms setup.
- If it DOES need to be a separate device, I understand it needs to be installed with the Teams Rooms software - but how do I assign the role of a Teams Panel to it, and how to assign it to a room?

Please note: This is to set up a test case. Wether it's feasible or not to roll this out into production will depend on how the test case works out.

Thanks for any input,
Marco

Comment: I continued my research, and what I have found out so far is: Yes, it needs to be a separate device, apparently as of current actually an Android device. On the device, a Teams Rooms App is required, and inside of this, there seems to be a Teams Panels App, which then, when logged in with the room credentials, seems to automatically turn the device into a panel. Most of this is guesswork from info bits and pieces I found around the internet, so the margin for error is quite high.

Comment: This question seems to be related to Teams Product. For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1).